# Fatal error with Ultimate Coupon plugin

Tags: plugins, errors

When I try to activate the plugin Ultimate Coupon I get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare like_content() (previously declared in /hermes/bosoraweb056/b557/ipg.ssgirlfriendscom/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-coupon-feed/ucfeed.php:3983) in /hermes/bosoraweb056/b557/ipg.ssgirlfriendscom/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Premium Coupon Plugin/ucfeed.php on line 3993

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Both plugins – *Premium Coupon Plugin* and *Ultimate Coupon* – declare the poorly named function `like_content()`. Disable the other plugin before you activate this one.

And tell the developer they should [prefix their functions](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/).